# What happens to future Potentials in the Buffy universe after the series finale?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

The Slayers we see in *Buffy the Vampire Slayer* become Slayers when they are (at least) teenagers.

In the series finale,

> Willow activates all the potentials in the world and they all receive the slayer powers.

Does this affect future potentials that weren't born yet?

> Do they get powers from the moment they were born? I can imagine the danger to the people around them when a slayer baby or toddler gets upset.

Is there any extra-canonical reference to what happens with them?

Comment: This might be explained in the comics continuation.

Comment: I mean, potentials that aren't born yet certainly get powers. Whether they get them *from* birth...I'm sure it's mentioned but I haven't checked yet.

Answer (score 3):

We see a considerable number of *former* potentials in Angel episode "[Damage"](http://www.buffyworld.com/angel/transcripts/099_tran.html)

[Andrew](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Andrew_Wells) turns up to collect a slayer who's gone off the rails. He brings with him 12 vampire slayers who operate as his personal bodyguard.

[image]

As regards those slayers who weren't activated at the end of Buffy, in the [continuation comics](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Big_City_Girl) we meet [Melaka Fray](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Melaka_Fray), a girl who was too young to have been called. **When she comes of age**, she becomes a slayer automatically, although she already had exceptional strength and agility (albeit not beyond human-normal limits) before this.

[image]

Comment: In Season 8, the slayer line is rendered dormant when Buffy destroys the Seed of Wonder and further so when magic is banished from the world somewhere in the 21st century. Melaka Fray is in the far future. There were initially only vampires ("Lurks" in their parlance) as the other demons have been banned. It's the return of those demons that reawakens the line.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I picked her as an example of someone who wasn't called at the time of The Calling. It's pretty clear that potentials are still being born, the only difference is that they all get called when they hit 16, rather than just one.

Comment: You cut off your thought before the picture `I think we can be reasonably sure that since all potentials are now actives, any ` - missing the rest of the sentence.

Comment: There's a pretty good book by Kiersten White which follows a new slayer after the destruction of the Seed of Wonder; "Slayer" https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07DNGHKRR/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1